# postgresql - how to get a handle on fields with ':' character in them

Tags: postgresql, openstreetmap

can't seem to get access to the addr:housenumber field in osm data using psql.

Here is the command I'm trying and I'm getting a syntax error:

```
select planet_osm_polygon.addr:housenumber from planet_osm_polygon, planet_osm_line where planet_osm_line.name ilike '%washington street%' limit 3;
```

for simplicity, this won't even work:

```
select addr:housenumber from planet_osm_polygon limit 3;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with **"**

```
select planet_osm_polygon."addr:housenumber" from planet_osm_polygon, planet_osm_line where planet_osm_line.name ilike '%washington street%' limit 3;
```

Comment: Sorry, doesn't work:  ERROR:  column "planet_osm_polygon.addr:housenumber" does not exist

Answer (score 2):

What about

```
SELECT "addr:housenumber" FROM planet_osm_polygon LIMIT 3;
```

?

Comment: thanks!!  it was "addr:housenumber" that worked....  I was trying 'addr:housenumber'  and would just end up creating my own string.  HOWEVER, I still can't get "planet_osm_polgyon.addr:housenumber" to work